# Mac Messages sending to Wrong Computer

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

I recently purchased a new MBP to replace an older one. However, I forgot to disable the iMessages feature on the old MBP before giving it to a family member. That family member and I both discovered that the messages that should be going to the new MBP are going to the old MBP.

How do you get the messages that were on the old MBP onto the new MBP? I do not have access to the old MBP, and the family member logged out without thinking and could not simply read the messages to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: it is not clear who has what Apple ID? Is yours still on the old computer and in use. Do you have a new one on the new mbp?

Answer (score 1):

Logging in with the appropriate Apple ID should allow you to send and receive messages as normal, including pulling all messages from the server as applicable.